# Is there a way to use console commands in the console version of Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, ps3

I have lost a valuable item, the Vokun Mask: I sold it early on in game not knowing I'd need it later on, and now I want it back. I have literally searched every merchant and cannot find it.

I've been looking around at [some questions on how to find or buy back items](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39209/once-something-has-been-sold-to-a-merchant-does-it-disappear), and the solutions they provide would be to use the console command option, but I believe its for PC only.

Is there some sort of way to do it on the Xbox 360 too, or are my items lost forever?

Comment: As far as I know unique items stay in every merchant's/shop inventory forever. Just keep on tracking back down the person you sold the item to, he/she will have it. Edit: Be sure to carry some gold :D

Comment: @Mars Is this true? I thought merchants periodically had their inventory wiped and rerolled. Quest items stay trapped in _your_ inventory and can't be sold, but I thought unique items could be lost forever. The Masks are quest-related, but they are not marked as quest items.

Comment: @Bryan I remember reading somewhere that you could sell the Claw Key items and they would be in the shop inventory forever. I tried this on my game, I sold to a shop 1 Dragon Priest Mask, 1 Unique Weapon and 1 Claw Key, waited outside 48 in-game hours and returned. The answer is... only the Claw remained :( Sorry. It only works with claws, but It may work with other unique items.

Comment: @Mars Thanks, very interesting to know (and, it seems, pretty unfortunate for the OP)!

Comment: yet another reason to switch to pc! spend the same cash that u could buy a console with, on a processor and graphics card. now buy a ps3 or xbox 360 controller, i use ps3 one. and now u have complete freedom to do anything with ur games such as mods and console cheats and use ur fav controller with xpadder!!!! ps3 not sure what u need for xbox

Comment: Related: [How can I find a lost item?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37365/4797)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Console commands are, in fact, PC only: PS3 and Xbox 360 owners do not get access to the console. If you sell an item and the merchant resets their inventory (usually after reloading the game), the item is lost forever. Your only solution is to load up an earlier save file.

Comment: I've edited the question to shift its focus from console commands to lost item recovery (which it sounds like what the OP is specifically interested in).

Comment: @BenBlank I think you went too far, making it an exact duplicate of [the question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39209/once-something-has-been-sold-to-a-merchant-does-it-disappear) already mentioned as being the solution for finding lost items. This question is specifically about seeing how to use that solution (or any solution) on a console.

Answer (score 0):

Xbox One and Xbox Series X/S players can use the [**Multi-Utility 6.1** by Selyb (XB1 port)](https://mods.bethesda.net/en/skyrim/mod-detail/4067343) mod to run console commands that can add or spawn items, among other console commands. For Xbox 360 players, the [original mod](https://web.archive.org/web/20221206002222/https://www.xboxchaos.com/topic/2839-multi-utility-mod-by-selyb/) requires a JTAG-RGH modded console.

[image: Screenshot of Multi-Utility 6.1 menu]

> This is a port of Selyb Multi-Utility 6.1 for JTAG-RGH Xbox 360 Skyrim players. This mod is a "console command"–like menu, which gives all Xbox players almost all PC console commands. What once was an exclusive feature to PC Skyrim is now available for Xbox One users.

> Usage: Equip Multi-Utility from Powers in the Magic menu.

Make sure to read the [UESP wiki article on console commands](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console), the [description on the mod page](https://mods.bethesda.net/en/skyrim/mod-detail/4067343), and the [post about the original Xbox 360 mod](https://web.archive.org/web/20221206002222/https://www.xboxchaos.com/topic/2839-multi-utility-mod-by-selyb/) first, as the instructions for running some of the console commands may differ from the PC.

Here are the item-related console commands that it supports:

> - Objects (For Add, Remove, and PAM, you will enter the item ID, then enter a quantity.)
>
>   - Add
>   - Remove
>   - PlaceAtMe - This can be used to spawn any base object including horses, enemies, items, and NPCs.
>   - Equip
>   - UnEquip