# Why can't I do anything any more?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have played Skyrim for xbox 360 for a long time now, but recently I've encountered a bug. I can't talk to anybody, I can't select anything, I can't open doors and I can't fight any more.

All I can do is walk and run. I can be killed but I can't fight.
Even if I load a previous save, when I was able to play, the bug is still present. 
Why is that? Am I the only one with this problem?

When I start a new game, it's working. But when you play 60 hours, you don't want to restart again. I think that the last update was a part of the problem. But when I uninstall it, the problem was fixed to 30%. Now, when I want to play, I can only start to one save in particular. The others, I can't do nothing.

Comment: Is it maybe a broken controller? Have you tried other games and been able to use all the buttons?

Comment: Try to clear your system cache and make sure the game is installed to the hdd

Comment: I tried but nothing works

Comment: If "nothing works", are you saying that other games don't work too?

Comment: no, the other game work

Comment: does it work if you start a fresh playthrough?

Comment: Maybe there is this feature in skyrim that you will become a ghost?

Answer (score 2):

For PC players with a similar issue - from the [UESP Wiki, "Skyrim - Glitches" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Glitches):

> - Sometimes, you will become stuck after a cinematic dialogue. Use the [console command](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console), [`enableplayercontrols`](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29#Player_commands) to retain your controls.
> - Rarely, it is possible to get stuck between objects, and be unable to move. This can be solved by fast traveling or using the [console commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console), [`coc <cellname>`](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#Untargeted_Commands) or [`tcl`](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#Toggle_Commands).

<sup>([Shamelessly copied from my other answer here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/115513/4797))</sup>

Comment: This won't help anybody playing PS3/Xbox360 (like in this question), but is a nice hint for PC-Players. Before someone is asking how to use this commands please read this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39955/is-there-a-way-to-use-console-commands-in-the-console-version-of-skyrim

Comment: @Streuner Yeah, I added that for PC players that might have encountered a similar issue and as per this [meta] post: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5488/4797