# I can't move in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can look around, but I can't jump, I can't attack and I can't switch from third-to first person. I brawled with Vilkas at Jorrvaskr to prove my worth for the Companions, and when I left dialogue, I couldn't move.

I can't open any menus, except for settings, and quest. I tried quicksaving and reloading, and I tried restarting, but neither worked. Can I get some help?
I'm playing on a laptop PC.

Comment: [Possibly related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114797/why-cant-i-do-anything-any-more)?

Comment: It's a bug. Reload a save from before you fought Vilkas.

Comment: If you just fought Vilkas, then you're outside, behind Jorrvaskr. Fast travel somewhere. Dragonkeep would work.

Comment: Related: [Stuck in the Night Mother's coffing during "Death Incarnate"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/201154/4797)

Answer (score 11):

For those playing on a PC, try these console commands to attempt to fix the issue. From the [UESP Wiki, "Skyrim - Glitches" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Glitches):

> - Sometimes, you will become stuck after a cinematic dialogue. Use the [console command](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console), [`enableplayercontrols`](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29#Player_commands) to retain your controls.
> - Rarely, it is possible to get stuck between objects, and be unable to move. This can be solved by fast traveling or using the [console commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console), [`coc <cellname>`](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#Untargeted_Commands) or [`tcl`](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#Toggle_Commands).

If you're not playing on a PC, you'd have to load an earlier save before the glitch happened as console commands can only be used on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a mod named FNIS Custom Animations, it can cause that problem, run the FNIS generator and it will work again normally

Comment: I don't get why some mods have such stuff like this?