# Stuck in the Night Mother's coffing during "Death Incarnate"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm having this problem with Skyrim that after I entered the Night Mother's coffin when the sanctuary was on fire, after waking up by Babette and Nazir I'm suck inside the coffin facing the Night Mother.

I can't move and do a single thing. I have reloaded my save several times hoping it would fix it to no avail.

UESP.net [claims](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Death_Incarnate#Bugs) that this bug is fixed by version 1.9.26.0.8 of the Official Skyrim Patch and since I have Version 1.9.32.0.8 it seems not to be fixed.

I have looked for a way to fix this bug for many hours but failed to find any. I'd be immensely grateful for any solution.

**UPDATE**
I am playing on PC and I also have tried many console commands such as `tfc`, `tcl`, `player.moveto`, `setstage`, etc.
The problem is I have no control over my character.
I event tried moving my character to Astrid's location which she noticed my arrival by saying a line of dialogue but I still can't move a muscle!

Comment: Hi Hamed, welcome to Arqade! You haven't mentioned if you're playing on a PC or a console - can you clarify? If you're on a PC you can try the console command 'tcl' to toggle collision, which may(!) allow you to move out of that location.

Comment: Have you turned Vsync off? If yes, temporarily enable Vsync and then try loading the save again. If you can't control your character, use the `enableplayercontrols` console command to regain control.

Comment: @galacticninja Thank you sir. With the command `enableplayercontrols` I was able to regain control. Now would you please put your comment in an answer so I can accept it? Cheers :)

Comment: @HamedMomeni Done. =)

Comment: This is one of those moments when I thought I was stuck also, it just turns out to be an incredibly long cut scene. If I remember correctly, after a while you hear some people moving about, clearing rubble, until you are rescued.

Comment: Related: [I can't move in Skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/115437/4797)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can't control your character, use the `enableplayercontrols` console command to regain control.

Answer (score -2):

I had this to. I had a mask that conceals your character. So i took it off and I unlocked the door that was closed with the unlock cheat. I did them both so i don't know wich one fixed it but now it works just fine.

Comment: This does not really answer the question fully.