# In Skyrim for PS3, I cannot walk

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently started mining in the Raven Rock Mine. I went a little further into the mine, but now I can't move.  It looks like I'm stuck in a gap between first- and third-person view.

I can't move, open menus (except settings and quest), fast travel, reload, save, crouch, or look around. I set my saves to "manual" to avoid the glitch that makes the game freeze while autosaving.  Basically, it seems like I'm screwed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have autosave on travel on? You can just load the save from entering the mine.

Comment: Oh, maybe that's what "i put my save setting of to manual" means? Then yeah, you're as screwed as it has been long since you saved.

Comment: Yeah, bassically my last save was about when the quest starts when you clear out the godforsakken mine from all the crap inside and obtain the bloodskaal blade .. Now i needed ebony for my daedric armor ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't move in Skyrim](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/115437/4797). Fixes require the use of console commands which are PC only. Unfortunately, you might have to load an older save as you are playing on a console.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in Elder Scrolls and Fallout games if you're not actively trying to avoid it. Try not to get into any crevices too much, and definitely don't jump while doing so.

On PC, you can use the console to extricate yourself.

Since you're on PS3, the only way to get out of it is to fast travel. Since you're indoors you can't fast travel, so you have to load a save.

Since you turned off the auto-saves, you'll have to load your manual save. **In other words, yeah you're screwed.** This is the situation the auto-saves are for.