# Do Items level up with you?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> The level 46+ version of Chillrend has the highest base damage of any one-handed sword in vanilla Skyrim. The heavier dragonbone sword from Dawnguard equals its base damage, while only the 60+ version of Miraak's Sword from Dragonborn surpasses it.

~ UESP

---

I got Chillrend when I was around level 25 and it did decent damage at that time but now I found that an Ebony Sword is the best I can use.

My question is, when I get to level 46 or higher, will Chillrend become stronger or did I make a mistake in taking it early?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [The Elder Scrolls Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Chillrend_%28Skyrim%29):

> ***Chillrend***
>   ....
>   **Levels**
>   "The damage, weight, value as well as the magnitude of the enchantment are based on the Dragonborn's level the first time
>   Riftweald Manor is entered. The best possible version is available at
>   level 46."

So yes, by taking it early in game, you are stuck with the lower level version of it.
There is no way to upgrade a leveled item in game.

**Possible Solution for Pc version**

Each version of the sword has its own Id.
[image: Chillred Levels]

With the console command `player.additem 000F8318 1` you can give yourself the leveled 46 version of the sword.

**Possible Solution for xbox 360/ps3**
Reload an older save, from before you entered the room and wait until you are at the correct level.
There are no ways to use console commands on xbox/ps3 according to [this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39955/is-there-a-way-to-use-console-commands-in-the-console-version-of-skyrim).

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but if you're on PC you can use mods to update the level of the item according to your character's level.

Take a look at [this mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/16090/?).

EDIT: Forgot to say this but yeah if you take it too early when you're a low level then Chillrend will stays at its low level form. Usually without mod the only way to make sure you obtain the item at its highest level form is checking out the wiki at which character level you should do a quest.